# Delete an old Stack Overflow account without access

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I've an old Stack Overflow account and current active Stack Overflow account,

The old account that I never used after asking a question, the account was created with my old jobs email address and now I don't have access to that email address anymore, but the old account have my website and some detail that confirms that its my account, I want to close/delete/abandon/inactive or any possible thing that makes it invisible to the world.

current account https://stackoverflow.com/users/829533/zzlalani

old account https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956942/zeeshan-lalani

Comment: Probably a good idea to email the Stack Overflow team at `team@stackoverflow.com` instead :)

Comment: What @Amal said, or go [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) choose "Other" and explain.

Comment: I think the team prefers the contact us page over the direct email, so @ShaWizDowArd's suggestion would be better.

Comment: Thankyou all for the suggestions, I have contacted them as suggested by @ShaWizDowArd. waiting for their reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can emailing them via contact-us https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact will help..

They replied with in one day, may be after doing all required verifications

> I've removed your old account. Let me know if there's anything else
>   you need.
>
> -The Stack Exchange Team